# KeyListeners with numpad?

Tags: java, user-interface, numbers, awt, keylistener

How do I use `KeyListeners` for the numpad? For example, if I make a `KeyListener` for 2, only the key for 2 on the standard keyboard works, not the numpad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`KeyEvent.getKeyLocation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyLocation%28%29) returns the location of a key press.

```
// KeyEvent e
if (e.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD)
    System.out.println("Numpad pressed!");
```

You can also use the keys `KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2`:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2)
    System.out.println("Numpad 2 pressed!");
```

Comment: @user3408559 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yup, sorry it wouldnt let me accept it too quickly after thread was made:)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the constants listed in the [KeyEvent Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), in particular the ones `VK_NUMPAD0` through to `VK_NUMPAD9`.  Those are the events you have to listen for.